# python: Finding min values of subsets of a list

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list that looks something like this 
(The columns would essentially be acct, subacct, value.):

```
1,1,3
1,2,-4
1,3,1
2,1,1
3,1,2
3,2,4
4,1,1
4,2,-1
```

I want update the list to look like this:

(The columns are now acct, subacct, value, min of the value for each account)

```
1,1,3,-4
1,2,-4,-4
1,3,1,-4
2,1,1,1
3,1,2,2
3,2,4,2
4,1,1,-1
4,2,-1,-1
```

The fourth value is derived by taking the min(value) for each account.  So, for account 1, the min is -4, so col4 would be -4 for the three records tied to account 1.
For account 2, there is only one value.
For account 3, the min of 2 and 4 is 2, so the value for col 4 is 2 where account = 3.

I need to preserve col3, as I will need to use the value in column 3 for other calculations later.  I also need to create this additional column for output later.

I have tried the following:

```
with open(file_name, 'rU') as f:  #opens PW file
    data = zip(*csv.reader(f, delimiter = '\t'))

# data = list(list(rec) for rec in csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')) 
#reads csv into a list of lists

#print the first row
uniqAcct = []
data[0] not in used and (uniqAcct.append(data[0]) or True)
```

But short of looping through and matching on each unique count and then going back through and adding a new column, I am stuck.  I think there must be a pythonic way of doing this, but I cannot figure it out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I cannot use numpy, pandas, etc as they cannot be installed on this server yet.  I need to use just basic python2

Comment: Code blocks need a blank like above them to work properly, and I can't do a 1 character edit. Also, how exactly are you getting the fourth column?

Comment: it is showing up correctly in my browser, let me try to reformat it.

Comment: actually, it was not.  sorry about that.  the line in the fourth column would just be the min for the records that correspond to the first column.

Comment: I don't understand how you are deriving the fourth values in the second code block.  Could you explain please?

Comment: updated description to explain how fourth column is derived with column headers

Comment: Before looking for the pythonic way, you should find a working way. Can you express the algorithm in pseudo code?

Comment: @Jasper what is "Pseudo code"? Pretend code?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode

Answer (score 0):

So the problem here is your data structure, it's not trivial to index.

Ideally you'd change it to something readible and keep it in those containers. However if you insist on changing it back into tuples I'd go with this construction

```
# dummy values
data = [
    (1, 1, 3),
    (1, 2,-4),
    (1, 3, 1),
    (2, 1, 1),
    (3, 1, 2),
    (3, 2, 4),
    (4, 1, 1),
    (4, 2,-1),
]

class Account:
    def __init__(self, acct):
        self.acct      = acct
        self.subaccts  = {}    # maps sub account id to it's value

    def as_tuples(self):
        min_value = min(val for val in self.subaccts.values())

        for subacct, val in self.subaccts.items():
            yield (self.acct, subacct, val, min_value)

def accounts_as_tuples(accounts):
    return [ summary for acct_obj in accounts.values() for summary in acct_obj.as_tuples() ]

accounts = {}
for acct, subacct, val in data:
    if acct not in accounts:
        accounts[acct] = Account(acct)
    accounts[acct].subaccts[subacct] = val

print(accounts_as_tuples(accounts))
```

But ideally, I'd keep it in the `Account` objects and just add a method that extracts the minimal value of the account when it's needed.

Comment: ok, thank you for the information.  I will play around with your code and my data set.

Comment: actually, the more I look at this the better of an idea it is.  Thanks again for this information!  I don't think I have enough posts to mark this as answered or give you the +1 or whatever.... I am really new here.

Comment: If I could ask one more question... if I have multiple fields tied to the subaccount, how could I put it in with the subaccount?

Comment: Ideally, youd create a class SubAccount and fill it by `accounts[acct].subaccts[subacct] = SubAccount(value)`. Also ideally an account object would just have a method to add a SubAccount.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using your initial approach.

Modify the way you import your data, so you can easily handle it in python.

```
import csv

mylist = []
with open(file_name, 'rU') as f:  #opens PW file
    data = csv.reader(f, delimiter = '\t')
    for row in data:
        splitted = row[0].split(',')
        # this is in case you need integers
        splitted = [int(i) for i in splitted]
        mylist += [splitted]
```

Then, add the fourth column

```
updated = []
for acc in set(zip(*mylist)[0]):
    acclist = [x for x in mylist if x[0] == acc]
    m = min(i for sublist in acclist for i in sublist)
    [l.append(m) for l in acclist]
    updated += acclist
```